# namespace and table sharing the same name (oops!)

Tags: c#, namespaces, conflict

First - I admit to my mistake!

But I need to know if I should try to fix it, or just live with the consequences.

I created a new solution (C#, VS2010) - let's call it 'F.PIA', for ease of reference.  One of the things this solution does is work with a SQL Server table that - yep, you guessed it - is also named 'PIA'.  So everything about my project - including the main namespace - is F.PIA.

I'm using F.A.PIA, to access the PIA table; this assembly includes a Table and a public partial class PIA.

In my solution, I can distinguish the two, but I find references to F.A.PIA to be clumsy (the actual names are significantly longer than that example).

So I tried to Refactor, w/o success.  I'm pretty sure the renaming changes something in the DataSetDesigner, or doesn't change something there (or a related item) - but I'm not nearly proficient enough to figure out what, exactly, goes wrong - nor how to fix it.  (Yes, I did have a working backup before the Refactor - YAY.)

Should I just leave it as is, and learn from my mistake for next time? or is there a way to rename everything *except* the references to my table, and get everything to behave?

Thanks! -- Scott M

Comment: You can try a `using FAPIA = F.A.PIA;` at the start of your code for better readability. Then whenever you want specifically want `F.A.PIA.Member`, you just do `FAPIA.Member`. There's no real reason not to have similar things in different project be named the same things.

Comment: *"There's no real reason not to have similar things in different project be named the same things."*  -- That's a mouthful.  [Some side reading on the topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options:

1. Create namespace alias for the C# namespace by the [using directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).
2. Create a class wrapper which handles the PIA table and provides a more user friendly way of accessing that table.
3. Fully quailify the namespace items for the C# namespace.
4. Rename the table, refactor, then change the name back.
5. Create a new solution which does not have the naming collisions.
6. Live with the idiosyncrasis as is...

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, OmegaMan; I was VERY tempted to try #4, but in the end I chose to live with my shame (#6).